# GCC error: "variably modified 'array' at file scope"—but using only constants

Tags: arrays, gcc, indexing

Cygwin GCC (4.8.3, 4.9.2) complains about the following code:

```
unsigned char array[ (unsigned short)((80.0f)/(5.0f)) ];
```

saying:

```
ModifiedVariably.c:3:1: error: variably modified 'array' at file scope [-Werror]
unsigned char array[ (unsigned short)((80.0f)/(5.0f)) ];
^
```

But there isn't any variable, and the result of the floating point calculation is cast to an unsigned before being used as a subscript.

Why are we getting this error, and how (besides not using floating point constants) can it be resolved?

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but as far as I could find out, these involved actually using variables as index, at file scope.

It appears that other compilers (e.g., [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) and the [TASKING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TASKING) toolchain) do not have this problem.

P.S.: The actual code has a number of `#define`'s; I took the resulting preprocessor output for simplicity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variably modified array at file scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789686/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope)

Comment: I had the same problem and I agree, most questions here don't actually use constants. But I found another question about actually using floating point _constants_ in the expression, with an answer. I've flagged this for duplication.

Comment: A more canonical duplicate target may be: *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)