# Floating point constant expressions in non-variable length arrays works in GCC - is it documented?

Tags: gcc

A non-variable length array declaration in [standard C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) must have an *integer constant expression* for its size ([6.7.6.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)). You are not allowed to use floating point expressions even if you cast them to an integer, with one exception - directly casting a floating point constant to integer: `(int)5.5` is allowed, `(int)(11.0/2)` is not ([6.6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)).

However, this works in GCC. GCC warns about it (using a [confusing message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789686/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope)), but otherwise generates code that works as I expect it to. These are equivalent:

```
int a[            6 ];  /* Standard C */
int b[     (int)6.4 ];  /* Standard C */
int c[ (int)(3.2*2) ];  /* Not standard - GCC allows it but warns */
```

This is fine, GCC is allowed to define rules above the default standard. In fact, since GCC is the *only* compiler available for my target architecture, I would not mind using this gcc extension.

My problem is: I can't find anything in the documentation that mentions that this should work. I would be grateful if someone could point me to the right place in the documentation, or - if you have some insight into this - tell me that I can't rely on it!

Comment: Well, Clang doesn't even warn: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZG9tJYKAXoqgrruw , maybe it interprets it as a VLA: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PKOFiHbxEQi4shgW

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah, it makes them into VLAs. It warns (error, actually) if you put them outside main: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZG9tJYKAXoqgrruw